# Setting the spawn position for a 3D object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an endless runner style game in unity where the floor tiles spawn randomly and endlessly in front of the player as they run and delete themselves after a certain distance behind the player this is all working fine and as intended however the individual tiles spawn about half way inside each other and as much as I try to debug my code I can't seem to effect them. Ideally, I want the code to do exactly what it's doing, but the tiles spawn end to end rather than inside each other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Tile_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] tilePrefabs;

    private Transform playerTransform;
    private float spawnZ =  5.0f;
    private float tileLength = 5.0f;
    private float safeZone = 7.0f;
    private int amtTilesOnScreen = 10;
    private int lastPrefabIndex = 0;

    private List<GameObject> activeTiles;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        activeTiles = new List<GameObject>();
        playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;

        for (int i = 0; i < amtTilesOnScreen; i++)
        {
            if (i < 2)
                SpawnTile(0);
            else
                SpawnTile();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (playerTransform.position.z - safeZone > (spawnZ - amtTilesOnScreen * tileLength))
        {
            SpawnTile();
            DeleteTile();
        }

    }

    private void SpawnTile(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject go;
        if (prefabIndex == -1)
            go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[RandomPrefabIndex()]) as GameObject;
        else
            go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[prefabIndex]) as GameObject;
        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnZ;
        spawnZ += tileLength;
        activeTiles.Add (go);
    }

    private void DeleteTile()
    {
        Destroy(activeTiles [0]);
        activeTiles.RemoveAt (0);
    }

    private int RandomPrefabIndex()
    {
        if (tilePrefabs.Length <= 1)
            return 0;

        int randomIndex = lastPrefabIndex;
        while (randomIndex == lastPrefabIndex)
        {
            randomIndex = Random.Range(0, tilePrefabs.Length);
        }

        lastPrefabIndex = randomIndex;
        return randomIndex;
    }
}
```

[stacked tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBzz9.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the length of a tile into account. Try changing this

```
go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnZ;
```

to this

```
go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * (spawnZ + tileLength / 2);
```

to add half the tile length to the spawn position.

Comment: I added an image to better show my problem, so the orange boarder is outlining each tile and as you can see they are stacked, changing what you have suggesting didn't do anything, but i could be doing it wrong I am fairly new to this sort of thing and I'm still learning.

Comment: @Bitlite can you please provide some more information? For example the actual length of the segment model, the inspector screenshot etc.

Comment: its 5 unity meters, when I originally made the plane I set the scale to 5 along the Z axis

Comment: @Bitlite did you use the plane, that is in Unity? Because that plane is 10x10 Unity units in size.

Comment: I spawned the default unity plane then set the z scale to 5 so would that make it 50m?

Comment: adding numbers to the end of the go.transform.position only makes the tiles spawn further away from the player at the start, but they still remain stacked on top of each other

Comment: You should update the spawnZ and tileLength to match the actual length of the tile.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want

```
go.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * spawnZ);
```

not position?

As you're spawning things relative to the world coordinate system.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

Comment: i tried this way but it didnt seem to change anything